kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer when deploying to Centos 9 stream
I'm using Deployer PHP v7 to deploy my project to my server into multiple folders (although this isn't specific to Deplyoer)
My server is Centos 9 Stream. I need to deploy my project into multiple directories on my server but I'm encountering intermittent SSH errors:

kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer Connection reset by [MYIPV6] port 22

It will work with multiple stops and starts, anotherwords, if I wait a few seconds and try again, it likely will work. Additionally, the deployment might take upwards of a few minutes to deploy all projects, and intermittently it will get killed by the above error.
What am i missing and what can i change to resolve this?
Here's my deployer php script:
<?php

namespace Deployer;

require 'recipe/common.php';
require 'contrib/npm.php';

require 'deploy/recipe/fudge-composer.php';
require 'deploy/recipe/fudge-nuxt.php';

// Project repository
set('repository', 'git@application-fudge:company/application-fudge.git');

// Shared files/dirs between deploys
add('shared_files', ['.env', 'brand-theme.scss']);

// Set number of releases to keep
set('keep_releases', 2);

// Timeout
set('default_timeout', 3600);

// Disable multiple SSH connections
set('ssh_multiplexing', true);

// Writable dirs by web server
set('allow_anonymous_stats', false);

$sites = ['site1', 'site2', 'site3'];

foreach ($sites as $site) {
    host("myipv6/$site")
        ->set('labels', ['stage' => 'forms', 'site' => $site])
        ->set('repository', 'git@application-fudge:company/application-fudge')
        ->set('branch', 'feature/fudge_v2')
        ->set('remote_user', 'root')
        ->set('deploy_path', "/var/www/forms/fudge/$site");
}

after('deploy:update_code', 'npm:install');
after('npm:install', 'deploy:vendors');
after('deploy:writable', 'nuxt:generate');
after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock');

